# Redundância com codeigniter + mysql

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Estou com uma duvida, vamos iniciar em um sistema a questão de redundância da base de dados, mas, como o codeigniter ira saber que existe outra base caso a principal fique inativa?

Existe algo próprio para o codeigniter identificar essa segunda base?

Comment: Basicamente pensei em algo em que testa a conexão antes, caso a primeira estiver indisponível ele entra na próxima, visto que a base de dados é a mesma, a unica coisa que mudaria é o ip do servidor. Por exemplo: IF(CONEXAO) assume o hostname X ELSE assume o hostname Y